# Scrapy spider logger doesn't recognize extra argument

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, logstash, logstash-configuration

I tried to add some context information to Scrapy spider log message and send it to Logstash, like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Status is %s' % response.status, extra={'status': response.status})
```

But it didn't work because I have a value from `extra` into `args` variable of LogstashFormaters(`args({'status': response.status})`.
But if I use directly module like:

```
logging.info('Status is %s' % response.status, extra={'status': response.status})
```

It works well. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: No, those extra fields weren't in `record` variable